# "ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed."

Tags: c++, vscode-extensions, freertos, ninja, espressif-idf

I'm starting to work on an old code without any doc (+2yo, all previous programmers are gone) doing RTOS on ESP32, using VSCode with Espressif-IDF (v4.4, because v5 doesn't work yet) on Windows 11.
I firstly managed to build and flash the code simply after installing VSCode and then Espressif (with C++, Python and CMake Tools extensions) without errors, but then I installed Unity 2019.4.4f1 (as well as Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 for C++ and .NET Desktop development via Unity Hub) to work on another part of the project and since, impossible to build anymore.
I got several issues, as asked for here is the full error message (well not quite because it is too big, thus I cut out dir with [...]) :

[EDIT]

```
[1070/1083] Building CXX object esp-idf/ibNavSix/CMakeFiles/__idf_ibNavSix.dir/ibNavSix_err.cpp.obj
FAILED: esp-idf/ibNavSix/CMakeFiles/__idf_ibNavSix.dir/ibNavSix_err.cpp.obj
C:\Users\UTILISATEUR\.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-g++.exe -DMBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE=\"mbedtls/esp_config.h\" -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/build/config -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/include/esp_additions/freertos -
[...]
ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/BME680 -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Comms -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mqtt/esp-mqtt/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/tcp_transport/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-tls -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-tls/esp-tls-crypto -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Filters -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ICM_20948 -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/RTC -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/STC3115 -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Werror=all -Wno-error=unused-function -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -ggdb -Og -fmacro-prefix-map=D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS=. -fmacro-prefix-map=C:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf=IDF -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -fno-jump-tables -fno-tree-switch-conversion -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D_GNU_SOURCE -DIDF_VER=\"v4.4.4\" -DESP_PLATFORM -D_POSIX_READER_WRITER_LOCKS -MD -MT esp-idf/ibNavSix/CMakeFiles/__idf_ibNavSix.dir/ibNavSix_err.cpp.obj -MF esp-idf\ibNavSix\CMakeFiles\__idf_ibNavSix.dir\ibNavSix_err.cpp.obj.d -o esp-idf/ibNavSix/CMakeFiles/__idf_ibNavSix.dir/ibNavSix_err.cpp.obj -c D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix/ibNavSix_err.cpp
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix/ibNavSix_err.cpp: In function 'void ibnav_err_check_failed(ibnav_err_t, const char*, int, const char*, const char*)':
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix/ibNavSix_err.cpp:73:10: error: 'getUnixEpochInMilliSeconds' was not declared in this scope
          getUnixEpochInMilliSeconds(), err_code, ibnav_err_to_name(err_code), file, line, function,
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[1072/1083] Building CXX object esp-idf/Comms/CMakeFiles/__idf_Comms.dir/wifi.cpp.obj
FAILED: esp-idf/Comms/CMakeFiles/__idf_Comms.dir/wifi.cpp.obj
C:\Users\UTILISATEUR\.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-g++.exe -DMBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE=\"mbedtls/esp_config.h\" -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/build/config -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Comms -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/include/esp_additions/freertos -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/include/esp_additions -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc/esp32 -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/. -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/private_include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/heap/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/log/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/apps -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/apps/sntp -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32/include/arch -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/soc/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/. -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/hal/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/hal/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/hal/platform_port/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include/esp32 -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32 -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/soc -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/public_compat -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/xtensa/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/xtensa/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/driver/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/driver/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_pm/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_ringbuf/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/efuse/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/efuse/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/vfs/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_event/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_netif/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_eth/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/tcpip_adapter/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_phy/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_phy/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_ipc/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/app_trace/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_timer/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mqtt/esp-mqtt/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/tcp_transport/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-tls -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-tls/esp-tls-crypto -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/port/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/esp_crt_bundle/include -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/nvs_flash/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/spi_flash/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/fatfs/diskio -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/fatfs/vfs -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/fatfs/src -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/wear_levelling/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/sdmmc/include -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Peripherals -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/BME680 -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Filters -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ICM_20948 -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/RTC -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/STC3115 -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Werror=all -Wno-error=unused-function -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -ggdb -Og -fmacro-prefix-map=D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS=. -fmacro-prefix-map=C:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf=IDF -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -fno-jump-tables -fno-tree-switch-conversion -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D_GNU_SOURCE -DIDF_VER=\"v4.4.4\" -DESP_PLATFORM -D_POSIX_READER_WRITER_LOCKS -MD -MT esp-idf/Comms/CMakeFiles/__idf_Comms.dir/wifi.cpp.obj -MF esp-idf\Comms\CMakeFiles\__idf_Comms.dir\wifi.cpp.obj.d -o esp-idf/Comms/CMakeFiles/__idf_Comms.dir/wifi.cpp.obj -c D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Comms/wifi.cpp
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Comms/wifi.cpp: In function 'ibnav_err_t wifi_init_sta(const char*, const char*)':
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Comms/wifi.cpp:74:55: error: cannot convert 'esp_interface_t' to 'wifi_interface_t'
   if (esp_wifi_get_config(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &sta_config) != ESP_OK) {
                                                       ^
In file included from D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Comms/wifi.cpp:10:
C:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi/include/esp_wifi.h:827:48: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'esp_err_t esp_wifi_get_config(wifi_interface_t, wifi_config_t*)'
 esp_err_t esp_wifi_get_config(wifi_interface_t interface, wifi_config_t *conf);
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Comms/wifi.cpp:100:55: error: cannot convert 'esp_interface_t' to 'wifi_interface_t'
   if (esp_wifi_set_config(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &sta_config) != ESP_OK) {
                                                       ^
In file included from D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Comms/wifi.cpp:10:
C:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi/include/esp_wifi.h:813:48: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'esp_err_t esp_wifi_set_config(wifi_interface_t, wifi_config_t*)'
 esp_err_t esp_wifi_set_config(wifi_interface_t interface, wifi_config_t *conf);
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
[1073/1083] Building CXX object esp-idf/ibNavSix/CMakeFiles/__idf_ibNavSix.dir/ibNavSix.cpp.obj
FAILED: esp-idf/ibNavSix/CMakeFiles/__idf_ibNavSix.dir/ibNavSix.cpp.obj
C:\Users\UTILISATEUR\.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-g++.exe -DMBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE=\"mbedtls/esp_config.h\" -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/build/config -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/include/esp_additions/freertos -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/include/esp_additions -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc/esp32 -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/. -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/private_include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/heap/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/log/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/apps -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/apps/sntp -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32/include/arch -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/soc/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/. -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/hal/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/hal/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/hal/platform_port/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include/esp32 -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32 -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/soc -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/public_compat -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/xtensa/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/xtensa/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/driver/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/driver/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_pm/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_ringbuf/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/efuse/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/efuse/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/vfs/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_event/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_netif/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_eth/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/tcpip_adapter/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_phy/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_phy/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_ipc/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/app_trace/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_timer/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/nvs_flash/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/spi_flash/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/port/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/esp_crt_bundle/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/fatfs/diskio -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/fatfs/vfs -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/fatfs/src -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/wear_levelling/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/sdmmc/include -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Peripherals -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/BME680 -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Comms -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mqtt/esp-mqtt/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/tcp_transport/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-tls -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-tls/esp-tls-crypto -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Filters -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ICM_20948 -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/RTC -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/STC3115 -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Werror=all -Wno-error=unused-function -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -ggdb -Og -fmacro-prefix-map=D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS=. -fmacro-prefix-map=C:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf=IDF -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -fno-jump-tables -fno-tree-switch-conversion -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D_GNU_SOURCE -DIDF_VER=\"v4.4.4\" -DESP_PLATFORM -D_POSIX_READER_WRITER_LOCKS -MD -MT esp-idf/ibNavSix/CMakeFiles/__idf_ibNavSix.dir/ibNavSix.cpp.obj -MF esp-idf\ibNavSix\CMakeFiles\__idf_ibNavSix.dir\ibNavSix.cpp.obj.d -o esp-idf/ibNavSix/CMakeFiles/__idf_ibNavSix.dir/ibNavSix.cpp.obj -c D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix/ibNavSix.cpp    
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix/ibNavSix.cpp: In function 'ibnav_err_t ibnav_read_baro(baro_sensor_t*, float)':
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix/ibNavSix.cpp:240:29: error: 'getUnixEpochInMicroSeconds' was not declared in this scope
   baro->data.timestamp_us = getUnixEpochInMicroSeconds();
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[1075/1083] Building CXX object esp-idf/main/CMakeFiles/__idf_main.dir/main.cpp.obj
FAILED: esp-idf/main/CMakeFiles/__idf_main.dir/main.cpp.obj
C:\Users\UTILISATEUR\.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-g++.exe -DMBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE=\"mbedtls/esp_config.h\" -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/build/config -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/newlib/platform_include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/include/esp_additions/freertos -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/include/esp_additions -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc/esp32 -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/. -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/private_include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/heap/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/log/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/apps -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/include/apps/sntp -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32/include/arch -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/soc/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/. -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/hal/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/hal/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/hal/platform_port/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/include/esp32 -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32 -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_common/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/soc -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/public_compat -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/xtensa/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/xtensa/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/driver/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/driver/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_pm/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_ringbuf/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/efuse/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/efuse/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/vfs/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_event/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_netif/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_eth/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/tcpip_adapter/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_phy/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_phy/esp32/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_ipc/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/app_trace/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_timer/include -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/BME680 -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Peripherals -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Comms -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mqtt/esp-mqtt/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/tcp_transport/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-tls -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-tls/esp-tls-crypto -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/port/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/mbedtls/esp_crt_bundle/include -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/nvs_flash/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/spi_flash/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/fatfs/diskio -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/fatfs/vfs -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/fatfs/src -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/wear_levelling/include -IC:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/sdmmc/include -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/Filters -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ICM_20948 -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/RTC -ID:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/STC3115 -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Werror=all -Wno-error=unused-function -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -ggdb -Og -fmacro-prefix-map=D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS=. -fmacro-prefix-map=C:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf=IDF -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -fno-jump-tables -fno-tree-switch-conversion -std=gnu++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D_GNU_SOURCE -DIDF_VER=\"v4.4.4\" -DESP_PLATFORM -D_POSIX_READER_WRITER_LOCKS -MD -MT esp-idf/main/CMakeFiles/__idf_main.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF esp-idf\main\CMakeFiles\__idf_main.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o esp-idf/main/CMakeFiles/__idf_main.dir/main.cpp.obj -c D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/main/main.cpp
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/main/main.cpp: In function 'void tg0_alarm_isr(void*)':
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/main/main.cpp:205:36: warning: 'esp_err_t timer_spinlock_take(timer_group_t)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   timer_spinlock_take(TIMER_GROUP_0);
                                    ^
In file included from D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix/ibNavSix.h:13,
                 from D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/main/main.cpp:87:
C:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/driver/include/driver/timer.h:437:11: note: declared here
 esp_err_t timer_spinlock_take(timer_group_t group_num) __attribute__ ((deprecated));
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/main/main.cpp:205:36: warning: 'esp_err_t timer_spinlock_take(timer_group_t)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   timer_spinlock_take(TIMER_GROUP_0);
                                    ^
In file included from D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix/ibNavSix.h:13,
                 from D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/main/main.cpp:87:
C:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/driver/include/driver/timer.h:437:11: note: declared here
 esp_err_t timer_spinlock_take(timer_group_t group_num) __attribute__ ((deprecated));
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/main/main.cpp:226:36: warning: 'esp_err_t timer_spinlock_give(timer_group_t)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   timer_spinlock_give(TIMER_GROUP_0);
                                    ^
In file included from D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix/ibNavSix.h:13,
                 from D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/main/main.cpp:87:
C:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/driver/include/driver/timer.h:449:11: note: declared here
 esp_err_t timer_spinlock_give(timer_group_t group_num) __attribute__ ((deprecated));
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/main/main.cpp:226:36: warning: 'esp_err_t timer_spinlock_give(timer_group_t)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   timer_spinlock_give(TIMER_GROUP_0);
                                    ^
In file included from D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/components/ibNavSix/ibNavSix.h:13,
                 from D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/main/main.cpp:87:
C:/Users/UTILISATEUR/esp/esp-idf/components/driver/include/driver/timer.h:449:11: note: declared here
 esp_err_t timer_spinlock_give(timer_group_t group_num) __attribute__ ((deprecated));
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/main/main.cpp: In function 'void app_main()':
D:/Serieux/Stage/Stage_3A/LASSENA/Firmware/FirmwareRTOS/main/main.cpp:851:3: error: 'initCurrentTimeAtZero' was not declared in this scope 
   initCurrentTimeAtZero();
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

 *  Arrêt du processus de terminal "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command ninja ". Code de sortie : 1.
```

I tried uninstalling VSCode, VS Build Tools and Unity to start from anew (I manually deleted `.espressif` and `/esp`). Still the same error.

As there are a lot of non-fatal FreeRTOS include errors I supposed it might come from there, I have thus tried creating a `platformio.ini` file to import the project into the PlatformIO IDE VSCode Extension to add the FreeRTOS lib to the project but got another error while Pio configurate the project :

```
Successfully installed windows-curses-2.3.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 23.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\UTILISATEUR\.platformio\penv\.espidf-5.0.1\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Error: Missing the `src` folder with project sources.
========================= [FAILED] Took 16.57 seconds =========================
```

The `platformio.ini` file :

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = espidf
lib_deps =
  feilipu/FreeRTOS@^10.5.0-0
```

I then uninstalled PlatformIO IDE to add manually FreeRTOS files to a `/project_dir/freertos`, with no more luck (still some FreeRTOS errors and the same fatal error).

Here are the `include` that may cause problems :

```
/* FreeRTOS */
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOSConfig.h"
#include "freertos/event_groups.h"
#include "freertos/queue.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
```

Those are all FreeRTOS includes. But those includes do not work on other computers without preventing the code to build to the end and the program to work on the device.

I guess `initCurrentTimeAtZero()` is a built-in function from esp (or FreeRTOS) but I can't seem to find documentation about it anywhere and it isn't defined in the code.
If you haven't got an answer but some guides or specific tutorials I could follow I would be gratefull.

Comment: Note: VS Code is a front end that sits overtop a set of command line development tools. When you have a build error, the answer is almost never to reinstall VS Code because, it doesn't do anything. Instead, you need to check the configuration of VS Code (its json files) to ensure you're telling the underlying tools to do the correct things, Check the underlying tools that do the work, and of course, the code, because the code is where the staggeringly vast majority of mistakes will be found.

Comment: Best advice I can offer is to locate where `initCurrentTimeAtZero` should be. Google was no help here, which means it's not a part of a common, well-documented API.

Comment: İt seems include files weren't targeting. Could you add your cmakelists. Please define include files.

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the the full error message? One of the lines in the question is `[...]`. Most probably the relevant errors are within those (hidden) lines, probably it's the very first error.

Comment: The relevant error message in the question is `error: 'initCurrentTimeAtZero' was not declared in this scope`. Probably you need a working `#include` line for that near the beginning of `main.cpp`.

Comment: I replaced the error code by the full message and added the problematics `includes` to the question. I'll try solving those first (but again, they were already failing before and on other pc without preventing the build).

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

So if anyone gets into the same situation : the Espressif version was the problem. The code was written under Espressif-IDF v4.1 and I was using Espressif-IDF v4.4.
Uninstalling Espressif and re-installing it with the right version (View -> Command Palette -> ESP-IDF: Configure ESP-IDF extension, etc...) solves all fatal errors.
I also added to the `c_cpp_properties.json` file the necessary include paths. File follows.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\Users\\UTILISATEUR\\esp\\esp-idf\\components\\freertos\\include",
                "C:\\Users\\UTILISATEUR\\esp\\esp-idf\\components\\esp_wifi\\include",
                "C:\\Users\\UTILISATEUR\\esp\\esp-idf\\components\\esp_event\\include",
                "C:\\Users\\UTILISATEUR\\esp\\esp-idf\\components\\driver\\include",
                "C:\\Users\\UTILISATEUR\\esp\\esp-idf\\components\\esp_common\\include",
                "C:\\Users\\UTILISATEUR\\esp\\esp-idf\\components\\soc\\esp32\\include",
                "C:\\Users\\UTILISATEUR\\esp\\esp-idf\\components\\soc\\include",
                "C:\\Users\\UTILISATEUR\\esp\\esp-idf\\components\\esp_rom\\include",
                "C:\\Users\\UTILISATEUR\\esp\\esp-idf\\components\\xtensa\\include",
                "C:\\Users\\UTILISATEUR\\esp\\esp-idf\\components\\xtensa\\esp32\\include",
                "C:\\Users\\UTILISATEUR\\esp\\esp-idf\\components\\newlib\\platform_include",
                "C:\\Users\\UTILISATEUR\\esp\\esp-idf\\components\\newlib\\platform_include\\sys"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```